# SQL Server Merge (Sort of) and Tracking Updates

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-warehouse, etl

I have an ETL process that is, for this question's purpose, done entirely in T-SQL.

During the Extract phase, the current process is:

1. Truncate our "source" table
2. Insert all data from ODS table into our "source" table

However, I want to implement the ability to do an "incremental" load, which would consist of only inserting new data and updating changed data. So that process would be something like:

1. Set "archive" bit in "source" table (all data is now archived, i.e. unchanged)
2. Update existing data from ODS to "source" (set updated rows archive bit to 0)
3. Insert new data from ODS to "source" (with archive bit 0)

I am aware of the `MERGE` statement in SQL Server 2008+. However, my concern is how I can go about correctly logging which rows actually changed. If I just do a `MERGE`, I believe every row found is going to be marked as changed, even if the data itself is unchanged.

Are there any tricks to do this beyond specifying every single column in the update predicate? Or is there a better process to achieve what I'm trying to do? FWIW, I'd like to avoid a solution that involves SSIS if at all possible for reasons beyond my control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past I've implemented an "operation" flag on the ODS table and used the MERGE to determine if anything has changed between the source and the ODS. This requires a unique key and a timestamp from the source. If you don't have a timestamp you could conceivably use a checksum or something similar but those are full of their own issues. I flag the matching records that have a newer timestamp from the source as "U", records from the source that are not in the ODS as "I" and records that are in the ODS that are not in the source as "D". Then I fire separate procedures that perform merges between the ODS and the target table. This method worked very well when having to process only 3-4K changes per night out of a 30-40 million recordset.

Answer (score 1):

You can test the conditions of the columns that maybe changed:

```
MERGE TableA
USING TableB
ON TableA.Id = TableB.Id
WHEN MATCHED AND (TableA.Column1 != TableB.Column1 OR TableA.Column2 != TableB.Column2 OR ....)
   UPDATE SET TableA.Column1 = TableB.Column1,
              TableA.Column2 = TableB.Column2
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT VALUES (TableB.Id, TableB.Column1, TableB.Column2, ....);
```

In any case, you must be more careful with nullable columns.